# Joining: string and absolute path with os.path

Tags: python, string, path

Why is this not working, what am I doing wrong?

```
>>> p1 = r'\foo\bar.txt'
>>> os.path.join('foo1', 'foo2', os.path.normpath(p1))
'\\foo\\bar.txt'
```

I expected this:

```
'foo1\\foo2\\foo\\bar.txt'
```

Edit:

## A Solution

```
>>> p1 = r'\foo\bar.txt'
>>> p1 = p1.strip('\\') # Strip '\\' so the path would not be absolute 
>>> os.path.join('foo1', 'foo2', os.path.normpath(p1))
'foo1\\foo2\\foo\\bar.txt'
```

Comment: On my Python it works as expected.

Comment: @rubik: Do you happen to use *nix?

Comment: @ delnan: yes I'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When `os.path.join` encounters an absolute path, it throws away what it has accumulated to far. An absolute string is one that starts with a slash (ans on windows, with an *optional* drive letter). `normpath` won't touch that slash as it has the same notion of absolute paths. You have to strip that slash.

And if I may ask: where does it come from in the first place?

Comment: I got it by splitting a path that I need to ad to another path. I'm attempting to make a code that recursively copies files/dirs form one to another folder, but not in "real time", but by creating a diles/dirs list, and then later using the list for file creation.

Answer (score 4):

p1 is an absolute path (starts with \) - thus it is returned by itself, per the documentation:

```
join(a, *p)
    Join two or more pathname components, inserting "\" as needed.
    If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
    will be discarded.
```

Comment: So, to get the desired result, just change the first line to `p1 = r'foo\bar.txt'`.

Comment: Will `p1.strip('\\')` in this case work equally on Linux and Windows?

Comment: @marw it won't be enough if you have other kinds of absolute paths (e.g. starting with "/", or starting with a drive letter like "C:" on Windows). See, for example, the result of `ntpath.join('foo', 'c:\\bar')`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the target behaviour of `os.path.join` to join two absolute paths together, strip out the separator:

```
import os
p1 = os.path.join(os.sep, 'foo1', 'foo2')
p2 = os.path.join(os.sep, 'foo', 'bar.txt')

os.path.join(p1, p2.lstrip(os.sep))
```

If you want to modify the paths, you can also do cool things like this using list comprehensions:

```
# Make sure all folder names are lowercase:
os.path.join(p1, *[x.lower() for x in p2.split(os.sep)])
```

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that `os.path.join(p1, p2.lstrip(os.sep))` fails under Windows, as each path will have been prefixed by a drive specifier rather than `os.sep`. Since the two paths may reside under different drives, it's unclear what the right thing to do under Windows _is_ – which probably explains why `os.path.join()` silently refuses to do this is the first place.